# How to invoke an interface method with Mono Embedding?

Tags: interface, mono, mono-embedding

I load an assembly and from that a class of the object I want to create. From that class I check for interfaces (***mono_class_get_interfaces***) and find the interface class I want (IDispose).

I create the object with ***mono_object_new*** and call ***mono_runtime_object_init*** directly afterward. I then call ***mono_object_castclass_mbyref*** to cast the object to an interface reference. Then I retrieve the interface method I want to call (Dispose) from the interface class with ***mono_class_get_method_from_name***.

I call ***mono_object_get_virtual_method*** to make sure I have the correct implementation and then try to call it with ***mono_runtime_invoke*** using the interface ***MonoObject*** * reference and the interface virtual method ***MonoMethod*** * (args = NULL) -> which is unsuccessful.

I have also tried to call ***mono_method_get_unmanaged_thunk*** with the same parameter, that doesn't work either.

In both cases I get a value back for the exception argument. Problem is, I haven't found a way to look inside the exception...

Question is:

1. Is the sequence of calls correct to work with managed interfaces and call the correct (most specific) interface methods?
2. How to get more information on the ***MonoException*** (I assume the ***MonoObject*** * returned by invoke is a ***MonoException*** instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to invoke any castclass function to cast a managed reference to an 'interface reference': the value is the same.

Once you have your IDispose MonoClass* pointer, you should get the MonoMethod* for the method you want to call and pass that to mono_object_get_virtual_method(). The result of this function is what you should pass to mono_runtime_invoke().

For the exception, you can invoke the get_Message method method, for example, or any of the methods you'd call to deal with it if you were in C# code.

Simple tested code below, str is a MonoString*:

```
icloneable_class = mono_class_from_name (mono_get_corlib (), "System", "ICloneable");
iface_method = mono_class_get_method_from_name (icloneable_class, "Clone", 0);
iface_impl_method = mono_object_get_virtual_method (str, iface_method);
exc = NULL;
obj = mono_runtime_invoke (iface_impl_method, str, NULL, &exc);
```

The method is correctly invoked and exc will be NULL.

Comment: That basically sounds like what I have (except the cast - but that shouldn't hurt). I'll check the exception and see what it says. Thanx.

Comment: I added some simple tested code above, it works correctly in the test-invoke.c sample in the mono repo. Maybe the method you're invoking is throwing the exception?

Comment: Yes. The exception was thrown by the method. I used Trace.WriteLine in the Dispose impl. and that generated an exception that there was an error initializing the config system. I had trouble calling ToString on the exception but getting the Message property worked. I have tried to call mono_config_parse(NULL) just before mono_jit_init(_version) but that makes the init exit the application. I think the problem is that the code that embeds the runtime is not the process but a plugin, so I may have to initialize the config system differently..?

Comment: That likely means that System.Configuration.dll is not installed or could not be loaded or you need to call mono_set_config_dir () to an appropriate value.